# Workflow Manager Server 'Faulting application name : Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

Getting error on Workflow Manager server under event logs.

Application Event log id is 1000

> Faulting application name: Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe,
>   version: 1.0.40131.0, time stamp: 0x52ef34e1 Faulting module name:
>   KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x5315a05a
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352 Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d Faulting
>   process id: 0x1628 Faulting application start time: 0x01d04cd5b966ad0a
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Workflow
>   Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts\Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
>   277be834-b8c9-11e4-a2ae-0050569d29be
>
> .NET Runtime log id :- 1026  Application:
>   Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: Microsoft.Workflow.Common.FatalException Stack: at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.Fx+<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0() at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Answer (score 0):

The issue appear because of Microsoft.Activities.Hosting dll. To resolve this issue please use the below steps

1. Stop Workflow backend service. 2. Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.dll is crashing. You need to change this dll. Please ask Microsoft to share the dll with you. And then replace this dll to C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts and C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\WFWebRoot\bin. 3.Start->Run->type "services.msc" and find the workflow backend service, start that service it will work fine and you will not get this error message again.

If the issue still persist you have to raise the ticket with Microsoft . 
Hope this will resolve your issue.